# Making a livecheck from a Github release's assets

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am making a cask for [PCSX2](https://github.com/tellowkrinkle/pcsx2), but I have not been able to do a suitable livecheck for it.

The version of the app is not fully stated on the release's tag, but on its assets. Therefore I aim to get the version from the name of one of the downloadable assets.

With the current livecheck on the script I am getting `Error: pcsx2-dev: Unable to get versions`.

```
cask "pcsx2-dev" do
  version "1.7.0-dev-20220325"
  sha256 "6c5450718f88c6ff13613385fcac91e1c907aad707c3777463e74a2138eaf66e"

  url "https://github.com/tellowkrinkle/pcsx2/releases/download/macos-#{version[/[0-9]{8}/]}/PCSX2-#{version}-Mac-64Bit.tar.gz",
      verified: "https://github.com/tellowkrinkle/pcsx2/releases"
  name "PCSX2"
  desc "Playstation 2 Emulator"
  homepage "hhttps://pcsx2.net"

  livecheck do
    url "https://github.com/tellowkrinkle/pcsx2/releases/"
    strategy :page_match
    regex(%r{PCSX2-/v?(\d+(?:\.\d+)+-dev-[0-9]{8}\b)$}i)
  end

  app "PCSX2.app"

  zap trash: [
    "~/Library/Application Support/PCSX2",
    "~/Library/Preferences/net.pcsx2.pcsx2.plist",
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```rb
livecheck do
  url "https://github.com/tellowkrinkle/pcsx2/releases/"
  strategy :page_match
  regex(/PCSX2[._-](\d+(?:\.\d+)+[._-]dev[._-]\d*\b)[._-]Mac[._-]64Bit\.t/i)
end
```